# Volar Higher Order Parametrizations

Tags: implied-volatility, volatility-smile

I came across [this](https://www.volar.io/src/pdf/volcurves_CU_24Mar2016.pdf) presentation from volar.io. The authors show fitting examples for a flexible volatility smile parametrization in 5 to 8 parameters which is also able to fit the locally concave market implied volatility smiles around special events.

Does anybody know the details of their parametrization and can you provide a reference? In particular, is it a simple extension of their C3 parametrization where the Cn curve is given by

\begin{equation}
\sigma^2(z) = \sigma_0^2 \left( 1 + \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} \frac{1}{n!} \xi_i z^n \right)
\end{equation}

with

\begin{equation}
z = \frac{\ln(K / F)}{\sigma_0 \sqrt{T}}.
\end{equation}

I suppose this is not the case and there is more to it. Some reasons:

- Their examples look very stable on the wings which I would not expect from higher order polynomials. While they do not show too much extrapolation, their C5 and C6 curves on slides 31 and 32 look fairly well behaved in the wings (where they loose some quality of fit though).
- It might be possible that they define a lower and upper cutoff beyond which they use a different tail function (e.g. linear in variance) and impose smoothness in these points. However on slide 10, they explicitly write that they don't like "hacks" in the wings.
- Another "goal" states on slide 10 is for no-arbitrage constraints to be easy to incorporate. In the above setup, absence of butterfly arbitrage at all strikes used for the calibration creates non-linear constraints for an otherwise nice linear problem.

Comment: Interesting question, I was not aware of such developments. I wonder if no (static) arbitrage conditions can easily be accounted for under such a parametrisation.

Comment: @Quantuple: That will exactly be my follow up question once we know how the parametrization looks like. It is usually not difficult to compute the density by just differentiating - either by hand (Mathematica) or using AD. The question is if we obtain sth. tractable that can be easily incorporated as a constraint in the fitting. Also - can it be ensured for all strikes or just a selected set?

Comment: Completely agree with you.

Comment: @LocalVolatility There seems more to it, they claim this can be done in real-time so Mathematica or AD is not a likely solution.

Comment: It's just a Taylor expansion, given its fitted using data in the wings, it's still going to be stable there. It's only extrapolation where it starts to become bad.

Comment: @pyCthon given that it's just a Taylor expansion to the polynomial, they can get very good initial guesses to the Regression just using the simple algorithms that exist, and then integrate just a few times, it should take tiny fractions of a second...

Comment: In fact, you even use the same form in an answer you posted two days ago to someone else's question, have you found up more on it since then?

Comment: @will: Thanks for your comments. No - I haven't figured out more yet. I have updated the question a bit to address some of your points. I currently do use a polynomial parametrization for very liquid names that can model W-shapes but need to resort to non-linear optimization (interior point methods) to ensure absence of arbitrage. I thought they might have another solution.

Comment: @LocalVolatility: this may be a stupid question, but for very liquid names, why do you need to bother ensuring no arbitrage? just use smoothing splines or something and be done with it - if the option prices are really showing an arbitrage, then maybe there's another reason it's there, and in reality it's just not realisable. Presumably you're not using the term surface + dupire to get LV, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: I was also goign to say that i don't recall them showing any plots of the fits outside the fit range - it might start going crazy then...

Comment: @LocalVolatility did you manage to learn more on this topic? I'm even more interested than before since I'm currently exploring better ways to fit flagship European indices, that currently exhibit a strong concavity on the put wing for the May17 expiry due to French presidential elections.

Comment: @Quantuple - I implemented some parametrizations that are flexible enough to model these types of smiles, though I still don't know what parametrization Volar is using. One such parametrization is in point 2 of my answer to https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/30749. Another is using thin plate splines in prices subject to no butterfly arbitrage constraints. I am still very much interested in the Volar approach though.

Comment: @LocalVolatility Thank you for answering. Yes I already upvoted that answer, which I found spot on. I also implemented them some years ago, but I remember them being pretty slow (especially when handling constraints at the full-blown surface level). Maybe I should dig them out and have a look at the manner in which I implemented them. Thanks again for your insight.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a customer, and not familiar with the details of their parametrization, but on page 25 they imply that next 2 parameters (S5) are independent wing parameters.

Later on page 25 and 26 they imply that other parameters S6,S7,S8 are to introduce W-shaped wiggle for names like SPY, AAPL and GOOG.

Comment: I don't think that's what they're saying, more that the svi jump wings model has the two parameters to deal with the call and put wings, and that when they move up to 5 parameters they can do the same, but since the nature of the expansion is not the same, their parameters are not the independent.

Comment: I understand the nature of their S3 and the SVI5 parametrizations. What I am interested in is if the higher order parametrizations are extensions of those of if they just go back to polynomials with some linear wings attached.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for S3 volatility curve is explicitly given in one of the presentations on Vola Dynamics website. In fact, it is functionally equivalent to SSVI curve. BTW, the company name and the website address have changed. See voladynamics.com